# setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* CRASH

Tags: ios, authentication, crash, handler, sprite-kit

I'm trying to authenticate the user into Game Center, in a Game build by using Sprite Kit. 
I've got two Scenes: NewGameScene & MainScene. I wanted to do authenticate the user as soon as the game is lunched in the NewGameScene. The problem is when the user goes from NewGameScene to MainScene before the authentication is complete, then app crashes. Also when the app goes to sleep and then awakes it crashes, I think I'm not handling errors or there is something wrong with the setAuthenticateHandler. Here my code ->

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;
NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
        //[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) { OLD CODE!

        if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated)
        {


        }else{

            // not logged in
        }

    })];

} else {


    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");


}

}
```

Here is where I call the method in the initWhithSize

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

  //Checking for Game Center

  gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
  if (gameCenterAvailable) {
      [self authenticateLocalUser];
      NSNotificationCenter *nc =
      [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
      [nc addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
                 name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
               object:nil];
  }
}
```

-- EDIT --

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
      //ERROR!! Here I've got the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x1)
  }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what line does it crash? what kind of crash, error message? Add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I added the Thread 1 of the error in the EDIT version of the post.

Comment: do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html then post the actual line of error (if any) plus the last couple lines in the debug console/log

Comment: [_CUIThemePixelRendition authenticationChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154e129d0
2014-02-17 01:10:23.994 App[6975:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_CUIThemePixelRendition authenticationChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154e129d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18729b09c 0x193219d78 0x18729fd14 0x18729da7c 0x1871bd4ac 0x18724f6dc 0x18719c01c 0x187199b38 0x18cbbf830 0x18a1d80e8 0x1000d0330 0x193803aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: sounds like you did not implement authenticationChanged (a GK delegate method)